# Motherboard splash screen doesn’t show up and I can’t access BIOS

Tags: boot, graphics-card, motherboard, bios, nvidia

I'm unable to access BIOS. I have a 2070 Super with one monitor plugged in with DisplayPort and the other with HDMI. When my PC turns on both screens are blank until the Windows 10 login screen shows up. I can access the BIOS if I plug a monitor into motherboard with DVI. Is there any way I can get the motherboard splash screen to appear and access BIOS when the monitors are plugged into the graphics card?

Comment: Look to see if you can set the default graphics card in the BOIS, set it to your expansion card, and save it. see if that changes matters.

Comment: Try resetting the PC from windows.  When you click the `reset` menu option (windows menu, right click the power icon), HOLD DOWN SHIFT.  After windows shuts down and comes back up, In the menu that appears, select `Advanced Options` , then `UEFI Firmware Settings`  Might work.. might be the same as you have now .. Oh .. and BTW.. people misuse the word, PCs haven't had BIOSs for MANY years, [what you are referring to is your UEFI firmware](https://www.howtogeek.com/56958/htg-explains-how-uefi-will-replace-the-bios/).  Now you can simply grin when people misuse the word. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. Thanks. Here's what I did. I have an ASUS motherboard.

1. Plugged a monitor into motherboard with DVI cable
2. Accessed UEFI by pressing delete key on boot
3. Pressed F7 to enter Advanced Mode
4. Clicked on Advanced tab (between Ai Tweaker and Monitor tabs)
5. Clicked on System Agent Configuration
6. Clicked on Graphics Configuration
7. Set Primary Display to PCIE
8. Pressed F10 to save and exit

The splash screen now appears on the monitor plugged into HDMI.